# Setting $scope.items in Angular Binding

Tags: data-binding, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a service with the following function,

```
public object Get(AllUsers request)
{
    var users = XYZ.GetAllUsers();
    var userList = users.Cast<XYZ>();

    return new AllUsers
    {
        UsersAcc = userList.Select(ConvertToEntity).ToList()
    };
}
```

I am trying to get the results from angular controller.

```
    function UserAccountController($scope, $location, $filter, UserAccount) {
    @scope.items = function(){
    var abc = UserAccount.query();
return abc.UsersAcc

    }
    }
```

Here is my Service

```
angular.module('userAccService', ['ngResource']).factory('UserAcc', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/useracc/:id', {}, {
      query: {
        method: 'GET',
      }
});
```

I am new to angular service, and can't seem to make it to work.

Comment: You have `@Scope.items` in your controller instead of `$scope.items` which is also a function for some reason. You probably just wan't `$scope.items = UserAccount.query();`

Comment: UserAccount.query() returns two objects one of type int and other of type list of lists (UsersAcc). I am trying to fetch the lists by doing var abc = UserAccount.query(); return abc.UsersAcc, which isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an array object and return it. After the query is done you can populate that same instance with the list `UsersAcc`. Keep in mind that `$scope.items` will be `[]` untill the query returns with data.

```
$scope.items = getUsersAcc();

function getUsersAcc() {
    var dataArray = new Array();        
    UserAccount.query(function (data) {         
        var list = data.UsersAcc;
        for (var i = 0, c = list.length; i < c; i++) {
            dataArray.push(list[i]);
        }
    };
    return dataArray;
};
```